# Navbar changing colour on scroll, how does this jQuery work?

Tags: jquery

So I've basically copied some code from another question here for a navbar that changes color on scroll. This is it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
 var scroll_start = 0;
 var startchange = $('#startchange');
 var offset = startchange.offset();
  if (startchange.length){
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
       $(".navbar-default").css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
    } else {
       $('.navbar-default').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
 }
```

});

It's all working well and good (with necessary id/classes changed ofcourse), but I want to know how it works since I have no idea. I understand that this code is basically saying to change the colour of navbar once the top of the screen scroll past the top of #startchange. But that's it really, im not sure what all the offsets and scrtollTop are doing. Obviously, im fairly new to JS/jQuery. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary Offset() and ScrollTop() are JQuery functions. JQuery is just a library of Javascript functions. JS is the language that your browser interpret.

Let me give you real definitions:

**Offset():** Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

**SrollTop():** Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

Your code execute a function when document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

It is supported by 3 variables (var).

```
 var scroll_start = 0;
 var startchange = $('#startchange');
 var offset = startchange.offset();
```

And when the event 'scroll' of the document is detected the code calls a function that change some CSS properties from element with class 'navbar-default'. When condition is satisfied and you have scrolled a higher value than the offset of the element with id 'startchange' (#startchange)

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
       $(".navbar-default").css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
    } else {
       $('.navbar-default').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

Here is the [JQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) where you can consult each of the functions

Happy learning. Happy coding. Feel free to ask what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what about if I wanted to change when the function happens? In this code the css changes when the top of the screen scrolls past the top of #startchange, but what about if I wanted to make it change after scrolling past the botton of #startchange? There's no offset.bottom right?

Comment: No, but there is another function height(): Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of m:atched elements.

With which you can play to get in a variable the value of the bottom offset of an element. Just adding the height of the component to the value of OffsetlTop (offset.top + component.height)

Check here I answered some other JQuery request a little related with this, maybe it is usefull for you to see some examples. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43403139/7733724

Comment: You need to have in mind that JQuery doesn't provide general methods for specific scenarios but give us tools for total DOM 'Domination' (between others). What means you usually will find some usefull function or functions combination that let you do what you need with every DOM element for every scenario/situation. Most of JQuery expressions combine more than 1 function. Begining with $() is a JQuery function yet, that let us make a fast getElementbyId/getElementByClass JS function. Important to begin is to know these tools by knowing first the syntax, then the avaiable functions and practice

Comment: Thanks a bunch, managed to do what I needed to with your advice by defining a variable as $('#startchange').height then adding it to offset.top (scroll_start > (offset.top + variable)). I have upvoted but apparently i need 15 reputation or something.